# How to call a method from another form without creating a new instance of that form? #C

Tags: c#

I had a form 3 that contained a picture box that when clicked on a event was triggered . In the event an int was created called trk. A new instance of form 2 was created next in the event. The method called ShowDialog was called from form 2. The int trk was passed through as a reference to ShowDialog.

The code for form 3 is below.

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public Form3()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }


        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          int trk = 45;


            Form2 f2 = new Form2();

            f2.ShowDialog(ref trk);


        }
    }
}
```

The form 2 method ShowDialog is opened which creates an instance for a picture box. The picture box's size, image and etc are set in this method.
Form 2 code below

```
 public void ShowDialog(ref int trk)
            {
                //Assign received parameter(s) to local context
                int trk1 = trk;
             if (trk1 == 45)
                 {
                  PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();

                  pb.Image = testsim.Properties.Resources.railroad_crossing;
                  // pb.Size = new Size(50, 50);
                  pb.Top = 200;
                  pb.Left = 200;
                  pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;


                 pb.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(pb_MouseMove);
                  pb.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(pb_MouseDown);
                  pb.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(pb_MouseButtonUp);

                  this.Controls.Add(pb);


                     trk1 = 0;

                 }                 
        }
```

The overview of what was trying to be accomplished with this code was that when a picture box was clicked on in form 3 a picture box would appear in form 2. The code compiled successfully but when the picture box was clicked on in form 3 a picture box did not appear in form 2.

A into step was performed which showed that a instance of a picture box was created with all it's parameter but it does not show in form 2. How can I call a method from a different form without creating a new instance of that form?
Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: Try to set width and height of picture box.

Comment: I set the width and height of the picture box but the picture box still did not show up in the form.

Comment: You never actually Show() the form.  The kind of mistake induced by picking a bad name for the method.  You should not be writing code like this, simply add the PictureBox at design-time and set its Visible property to False.  So you only have to set it to *true* at runtime.

Comment: I didn't do show() because I didn't want another form 2 popping up. I wanted the image to show on the current form 2 that was up. I added a picture box and set the visibility to false. I set it to true in the runtime and the picturebox still did not show.

Comment: My question would be then is there a way to reference form 2 so that a method from form 2 can be called without making a new instance of form 2? I do not want another form 2 popping up every time I use the click event.

Comment: I didn't read the question, but `public` [`static`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx) methods can be accessed without creating a new instance of the class